# How to import large number of global variables without listing each one? (Python)

Tags: python, import

```
DEFINE1 = 1
DEFINE2 = 2
DEFINE3 = 3
...
DEFINE10 = 10
```

Let's say one file has 10 global constants that I want to import into another file.

Instead of doing the following, is there any simpler way to import all the global constants without doing something like: from file_one.py import *. I don't want it to import the entire file, just the global variables.

```
from file_one.py import DEFINE1, DEFINE2, DEFINE3, ..............
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, I think it's perfectly okay to create a lot of constants like you're doing and put them all in a `constants.py` file and then do a `from constants import *` - I do this myself all the time.  So long as all of my constants are defined in that file, I know exactly where to look when I need to figure out where `SOME_CONSTANT` came from.

But I'll assume for the moment that you have a module with a lot of constants and they all consist of upper-case letters, numbers, and underscores.  At that point you can do something very hackish like

```
import re, file_one
for name,val in file_one.__dict__.items():
    if re.match("[A-Z0-9_]+", name):
        globals()[name] = val
```

I would strongly advise against this sort of hackery, but this would make it possible to automatically import the constants you define without having to list them individually.

Comment: While I implemented this exact same pattern last night in a script, I realized the most significant impact that it will have is that it'll foul up intellisense/code-completion in most IDEs unless they actually execute the script as part of gathering tokens. That's pretty much why I reverted to the explicit method of listing them all manually - so my IDE would quit showing their uses in wavy red underlines. If you don't give two shakes about that - this method is a great solution for the problem!

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that all upper-case names are global constants:

```
import file_one
g = globals()
for key in dir(file_one):
    if key.isupper():
        g[key] = getattr(file_one, key)
```

Or shorter:

```
import file_one
globals().update((key, getattr(file_one, key)) for key in dir(file_one)
                                               if key.isupper())
```

Having said that: Don't do it.  Explicit is better than implicit.  You should put these constants in a separate module and import them in both modules using `from constants import *`.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just have a file with the constants, and call:

```
from file_constants import *
```

..?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest having an object that stores your constants. For example, something like this:

```
# file_one.py
class _COLORS:
    BLUE = 0
    RED = 1
    GREEN = 2
COLORS = _COLORS()
```

Then you can reference it like this:

```
# file_two.py
from file_one import COLORS
print COLORS.BLUE #prints 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
class _Constants(object): pass

constants = _Constants()
constants.DEFINE1 = 1
constants.DEFINE2 = 2
...
```

Then to import these, do (leave off the '.py' from the import):

```
from file_one import constants
```

This also allows you to group your constants into meaningful subsets too:

```
colors = _Constants()
colors.RED = (255,0,0)
colors.GREEN = (0,255,0)
colors.BLACK = (0,0,0)
colors.WHITE = (255,255,255)

linetypes = _Constants()
linetypes.SOLID = 0
linetypes.DOTTED = 1
linetypes.DASHED = 2
```

And just import colors or linetypes.  This will give your constants something of a namespace within your module, so that you can limit your imports, and avoid some name clashing.